# jQuery / ajax data container + organization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My dad and I are working on a project where we'd like to create a script that calls in data when a number is submitted into a form. For example, when you type in your ID number then press ENTER or SUBMIT, the form will print/display information. This is a project for school, so when a student submits their ID number it will read their first period class, for example.

I have the following script code to set up the form:

```
<form id="firstPeriod" action="firstPeriod.html">
  <p>Find your first period.</p>
  <p><label>Student no.: <input type="text" name="studentNo"></label></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Find it"></p>
  <p id="result"></p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#firstPeriod').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({ // Send the request behind the scenes
              url: $(this).attr('action'), // Send it here
              data: $(this).serialize(), // With this student no.
              success: function(data) {
                    $('#result').html(data); // Display the resulting HTML
              },
              error: function(jqxhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    $('#result').html('No results found. Please check your number and reenter'); // Notify an error
              }
        });
        return false; // Prevent the normal form submission
  });
```

});

My question is, what would be the best way to organize the data? An array, HTML, etc.? There are quite a lot of ID numbers and are currently set up in an HTML table, but that doesn't seem to work in calling the information. And I'd like for the data to be specific. So when a specific ID number is typed in, it reads a specific answer. Right now my problem is when I type in a number it reads several classes.

If there are any suggestions/advice/other posts that could help me, I'd be grateful. I have solid HTML, CSS experience but I'm still learning JS and jQuery so this is a little new for me. Thanks!

Comment: You could use `JSON`

Comment: When you run the ajax call, you are making a call to the server for info.  Are you asking how to organize the info on the server itself?

Comment: Yes, not sure how to organize the info on the server. We assumed a second file would be necessary to arrange the data, then put that file on the server with the correct format so the Ajax can read it and pull up the request info. If we didn't want the information to come from the server, would JSON be the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, Updated

Note, added `value` attribute to `input type="text"` element

```
<input type="text" name="studentNo" value="" />
```

substituted `.submit()` for `.on("click")` at `input type="submit"` element

---

Two possible approaches could be 1) using `HTML` to store data, `.load()` to retrieve fragment identifier within `html` file; or 2) storing data using `JSON`, retrieving file using `php`

html at `firstPeriod.html`

```
<div id="0">data 0</div><div id="1">data 1</div>
```

javascript

```
$(function() {
  var form = $("#firstPeriod");
  $("input[type=submit]").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var data = form.serializeArray();
    // where `data[0].value` is `id`; e.g.; `0` 
    var id = data[0].value;         
    $("#result").load(form.attr("action") +" #"+ id)
  })
})
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/4onHf9jlJTyDei1zo9IC?p=preview

---

`JSON`

`0.json`

```
  {
    "0":"<div id='0'>data 0</div>"
  }
```

`1.json`

```
  {
    "1":"<div id='1'>data 1</div>"
  }
```

javascript

```
  $(function() {
    var form = $("#firstPeriod");
    $("input[type=submit]").on("click", function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation();
       var data = form.serializeArray();
       // where `data[0].value` is `id`; e.g.; `0` 
       var id = data[0].value;         
       $.post("data.php", {id:id}, function(result) {
         $("#result").html(result[id])
       }, "json")
     })
   })
```

php

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $file = $id . ".json";
    if (file_exists($file)) {
      $jsondata = file_get_contents($file);
      $id_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
      echo json_encode($id_data);
    };
  }
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you. I went with the HTML/JS route, it's similar to what I set up initially. When I organize the HTML file with multiple divs, it prints/displays all the divs. Do I need to update anything in the script so it only displays one?

Comment: @user6301101 There are a couple errors at `js`, will update post

Comment: @user6301101 _"Any reason this doesn't work in Chrome?Any reason this doesn't work in Chrome?"_ Can you describe "doesn't work"?

Comment: When I open the file in Chrome and click "Find it", the answer does not appear below. When I open the file in Firefox or Safari and click "Find it," the corresponding div/answer displays below as intended.

Comment: @user6301101 Are any errors or messages logged at `console`?

Comment: Console says: "Cannot load. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

Comment: @user6301101 Is `url` `file:` protocol?